# How to ensure app is deployed before moving to next stage using DevOps YAML pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-api-management

I have a yaml pipeline that is deploying a web API application. Immediately after deployment, I need to run another job/task, that updates APIM with the new endpoint swagger file.

The problem I have, is that the endpoint is not available for 'some' time when performing the `apim@5` task. This results in a failure.

Is there any way I can force the pipeline to wait until the endpoint returns `200 OK` before continuing? Maybe with a timeout?

Here's the pipeline:

```
- stage: DeployApp
  variables:
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployApiApp
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            inputs:
              ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
              azureSubscription: 'MySub'
              appType: 'webAppLinux'
              WebAppName: $(appName)
              packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/myapp.zip'
              RuntimeStack: 'DOTNETCORE|5.0'
         
  - job: 
    dependsOn: 
    - DeployApiApp
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    displayName: Update APIM APIs
    steps:
      - task: apim@5
        inputs:
          ConnectedServiceNameARM: 'MyServiceConnection'
          ResourceGroupName: 'rg-$(resourceSuffix)'
          ApiPortalName: 'apim-$(resourceSuffix)'
          OpenAPISpec: 'v3'
          Format: 'json'
          Authorization: 'None'
          SwaggerPicker: 'Url'
          swaggerlocation: 'https://$(appName).azurewebsites.net/swagger/v1/swagger.json'
          targetapi: 'myApi'
          DisplayName: 'MyApi'
          pathapi: 'api'
          subscriptionRequired: false
          TemplateSelector: 'CORS'
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually put a smoke test step right after deployment to make sure the app is running and warmed-up.

Something like:

```yaml
- script: curl https://$(appName).azurewebsites.net
  displayName: 'smoke test'
```

If you expect it to take more time and possibly throw some errors before it's ready, you can add retries:

```yaml
- pwsh: |
    $url = "https://$(appName).azurewebsites.net"
    write-host "testing '$url'"
    $retries = 5
    do {
      $retries -= 1
      curl --show-error --fail $url
      if ($lastExitCode -ne 0 -and $retries -ge 0) {
        start-sleep -seconds 5
      }
    } while($retries -ge 0)
  displayName: 'smoke test'
```

Answer (score 1):

I come up with a solution by using [Delay Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/delay?view=azure-devops) and [Invoke REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops) for this type of scenario. These are run on an [agentless Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agentless-tasks)

I'll give you a visual editor for the pipeline just for your understanding, From the below visual editor image you can see I set a delay of 10 min after that I call a invoke rest API which can help to call your API and get the response you need

[image]